# Invalid Column Name '@FileName-- value'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting 'Invalid Column Name '@FileName-- value'' ERROR WHILE executing below stored procedure. I tried to find the root cause of the issue with no luck...Please suggest me where i am wrong.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ICLExtract_GetFile]

 @FileName Varchar(50),     
 @Image_Path    Varchar(50) Output,     
 @FIleNameList  varchar(4096) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @strProcName  varchar(255) 
    SET @strProcName = 'usp_ICLExtract_GetFile'
    DECLARE @strSQL1 varchar(1024), @strSQL2 varchar(1024)
    DECLARE @strFileName Varchar(50)
    DECLARE @intErrorReturn int 
    SET @intErrorReturn = 0
    SET @FileNameList = ''
    SET @Image_Path = ''    
    SET @strSQL1 = N'SELECT tbl_ICLExtCashLetter.Image_Path from  tbl_ICLExtCashLetter  INNER JOIN tbl_ICLExtFile  on [tbl_ICLExtCashLetter].ICLExtFileUID = [tbl_ICLExtFile].ICLExtFileUID  where tbl_ICLExtFile.FileName = ' + @FileName --This line cause error

    /*==============================================================================
    * Run the query'
    *==============================================================================*/
    SET @strSQL2 = 'DECLARE curCategory INSENSITIVE SCROLL CURSOR FOR ' + @strSQL1
    EXEC(@strSQL2)
    SELECT @intErrorReturn = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorReturn <> 0) GOTO usp_ICLExtract_GetFile_Error
    OPEN curCategory
    SELECT @intErrorReturn = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorReturn <> 0) GOTO usp_ICLExtract_GetFile_Error
    FETCH NEXT FROM curCategory INTO @strFileName
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN
    SET @FileNameList = @FileNameList + @strFileName + ';'
    SET @Image_Path  = @Image_Path  + 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM curCategory INTO @strFileName
    END
    CLOSE curCategory
    DEALLOCATE curCategory
    RETURN(0)   
usp_ICLExtract_GetFile_Error:
    RETURN(@intErrorReturn)
END
```

Comment: Do a bit of Google... http://bit.ly/1fZ9XWj

Answer (score 1):

replace line with this

```
 SET @strSQL1 = N'SELECT tbl_ICLExtCashLetter.Image_Path from  tbl_ICLExtCashLetter  INNER JOIN tbl_ICLExtFile  on [tbl_ICLExtCashLetter].ICLExtFileUID = [tbl_ICLExtFile].ICLExtFileUID  where tbl_ICLExtFile.FileName = ''' + @FileName +'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
N'SELECT tbl_ICLExtCashLetter.Image_Path from  tbl_ICLExtCashLetter  
INNER JOIN tbl_ICLExtFile  on [tbl_ICLExtCashLetter].ICLExtFileUID = 
[tbl_ICLExtFile].ICLExtFileUID  where tbl_ICLExtFile.FileName = ''' + @FileName + ''''
```

you have to pass value between apostrophes `'`.